# transformation methods for digital filters

Tags: lowpass-filter, digital-filters, analog-to-digital

i have the following question:
in digital filter design what's the difference between the methods of transformations :
bilinear vs impulse invariance vs Euler vs step invariance.
thank you!

---

[image]

Here is a picture of what I got.

Comment: Where/how were you introduced to these terms and what confused you in the explanations given? This may help simplify the answer into something that won’t replace what you can find in introductory DSP textbooks (and be as lengthy)

Comment: i just want to know how to analyze the output of each method, i made a low pass filter using these methods and i got a certain output , i wan't to know where the difference lie

Comment: see the picture that i commented with

Comment: Maybe this post can help? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62537/frequency-warping-when-integrators-are-replaced-with-backward-euler-and-forward/62541#62541

Comment: @imene Please [**edit your question**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/86536/edit) to add details, do not put the extra information in an "answer".